# При использовании RxJava обновления подписчику не приходят

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxjava2

Я только начал изучать RxJava и столкнулся с проблемой.

У меня есть метод который делает запрос в Firebase Storage  и при удачном исходе возвращает Observable(Uri)

```
public Observable<Uri> get() {
        final PublishSubject<Uri> subject = PublishSubject.create();
        Variables.storageReference.child("images/" + id).getDownloadUrl()
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        uri -> subject.onNext(uri)
                );
        return subject;
    }
```

Другой метод получает этот Observable и что-то дальше выполняет.

```
get()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(
                        uri -> {
                            // ...
                        }
                );
```

Позже я добавляю файл в Firebase Storage и по логике это должно выполниться ещё раз (т.к. я подписался на обновления). Но Это срабатывает один раз и всё. Может я просто что-то не допонимаю до конца

Comment: addOnSuccessListener скорее всего подразумевает всего одно срабатывание. Посмотрите есть ли там другие слушатели

Comment: Вряд ли, так как сначала срабатывает слушатель addOnFailureListener, а потом вообще не запускается метод

Comment: Если слушателей нужных нет, то, значит это нельзя сделать. Ну или как минимум надо брать другие классы. Сам по себе rx не делает магии. Если в subject данные придут только раз, он не будет излучать новые из ниоткуда.

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим комментарием, `getDownloadUrl()` возвращает Таск, корый выполняется только раз. Как вариант можно использовать `Observable.interval()` что бы делить запрос каждые n секунд.